# Laravel timeout on auth login

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel-5

Laravel 5.3 - My goal is to send login form via ajax to login controller (AuthenticatesUsers trait), and to get a response (json would be ok), so i could set timeout before redirect to "dashboard" section (authenticated). I need that timeout for some frontend stuff.
So could it be done? If it could, hint would suffice. 
Thanks in advance.

Javascript example:

```
$("#login-form").submit(function (e) {

var url = "/login"; // the script where you handle the form input.

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache : false,
    url: url,
    data: $("#login-form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
    success: function () 
    {       //Do the timeout part, then redirect
            topbar.addClass('success');
            form.addClass('goAway');
            article.addClass('active');
            tries = 0;

    },
    error: function () {
        location.reload(); 
        input.addClass('disabled');
        topbar.addClass('error');
    }

});});
```

Login form is sent via post, and i would like to do a redirect by myself, not via controller, and my main concern is the csrf token on javascript redirect would change.

edit:
Another thing that I discovered is including token inside ajax setup:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': _token}
});
```

and prevent form default action:

```
$("#login-form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
```

Here's my login form (all js and css is included in parent view):

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<form class="form form-horizontal" id="login-form" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="forceColor"></div>
    <div id="logosm_wrapper">
        <img id="logosm_login" src="img/ipism_100x50.png" alt="logo" >
    </div>
    <div class="forceColor"></div>
    @if (count($errors))
    <div class="topbar error">
    @else
    <div class="topbar">
    @endif
        <div class="spanColor"></div>
        <input id="email" type="email" class="input form-control" name="email"  placeholder="E-mail" value="{{ old('email') }}">
    </div>
    @if (count($errors))
    <div class="topbar error">
    @else
        <div class="topbar">
    @endif
        <div class="spanColor"></div>
        <input id="password" type="password" class="input form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
    </div>
    <button class="submit" id="submit">Login</button>
    <!--input class="submit" id="submit" type="submit"  value="Login"-->
</form>
@endsection
```

This is working as intended by Laravel Auth, my intention was to green out input fields on authorisation via JS, and then redirect user to dashboard...

Comment: Have you looked at https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-ajax-tokenmismatchexception

Comment: Yes, i've looked it up, it isn't my main concern, because you can turn off token validation (get rid off).  The thing is can you redirect auth by yourself with all the data after validation of user

Comment: Why is it a problem if the csrf_token changes after redirect ?

Comment: @shock_gone_wild - it throw's me an TokenMismatchException...

Comment: You mean the next time you do an ajax request? If I understand you correctly, then you want to redirect to dashboard after a successful login? After redirection the csrf_key is renewed. And you have to include the new csrf token for following requests....

Comment: @shock_gone_wild, no, the form is handled by php itself (post action), and i want to bypass it, but when i try to bypass it (on form submit), it sends two http requests, one being get and another post. so it authenticates me, and redirects before i had a time to set timeout.

Comment: but if you use e.preventDefault()  there should be no redirect afert submitting that form, unless the error method is executed. Could you please post your login form, too ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest u add this in your ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  ....    
  async     : false,
 ....
```